# Can HSV images be used for CNN training

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I am currently working on [fingers-count](https://www.kaggle.com/koryakinp/fingers) deep learning problem. When you look at the dataset, images in the training and validation set are very basic and are almost the same. The network can achieve high training and validation accuracies. But when it comes to prediction in real-life images, it performs very badly(this is because the model has been trained on very basic images).

To overcome this, I converted the training and validation images to HSV(Hue-Saturation-Value) and trained the model on new HSV images. Example of 1 such image from new training set is:

[image]

I then convert my image from real life to HSV and pass it to model for prediction. But still, the model is not able to predict correctly. I assumed that since the training images and predicting image are almost same after applying HSV, the model should be predicting good. Is there something which I am thinking incorrectly here? Can HSV images be actually used for training CNN?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the overfitting issue, and your model only memorize the simple samples  of the training set and in contrast it can not generalize to more complex and diverse data.

In the context of Deep Learning there are various methods to avoid overfitting and I think you don't need to transform your input to HSV necessarily. First of all you can apply various **data augmentation** methods like random crop or rotation to create various versions of your data. If this method does not work, you can use a smaller model or applying techniques such as **Drop Out** or **Regularization**.
Here is a good tutorial from [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).